# Access https backend with ingress and traefik

Tags: kubernetes, haproxy, traefik, lets-encrypt

I am trying to use 'Kubernetes Ingress with Traefik, CertManager, LetsEncrypt and HAProxy' for certificates management.

What I want to do is use certificates in my application which deployed on kubernetes.

My application contains following services:

> my-app1   NodePort    10.43.204.206     16686:31149/TCP

> my-app2 NodePort   10.43.204.208     2746:30972/TCP

So for my-app1 without certificates I was accessing it as `http://{IP}:31149/app1`. And with certificates I am now accessing it as `https://my-dns.com/app1`. For this I am using [this](https://allanjohn909.medium.com/kubernetes-ingress-traefik-cert-manager-letsencrypt-3cb5ea4ee071) link. I created following ingress resource:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: prod-ingress
  namespace: my-ns
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.tls: "true"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - "my-dns.com"
    secretName: prod-cert
  rules:
  - host: "my-dns.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /app1
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-app1
            port:
              number: 16686
```

But for my-app2 without certificates I was accessing it as `https://{IP}:30972/app2`. So as I am already using https for my-app2 but I want to also use certificates for this service.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: hope you have used the prod one in link instead of the staging one. plus you are accessing the it on https try once with https and check. you have attached the secret ingress right ?

Comment: Yes I am using prod setup. Also I am trying to access dashboard on https. I am able to access nginx and httpd services securely as given in link. But not able to access dashboard from my application securely.

Comment: you can use an ingress to an upstream https service of course, but if that service is deployed with a self-signed certificate, you will run into troubles.

Comment: @MarianTheisen can you please provide example for using an ingress to an upstream https service. Basically I am trying to upstream kubernetes dashboard service by disabling its self signed certificates.

Comment: @RupeshShinde If your issue is resolved please post it. So, that it will be helpful for other community members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was, I was deploying my application with self signed certificates. So because of this I am getting issue while accessing my dashboard.

So now I just disabled self signed certificates in my application. And now I am able
to access dashboard with domain name `https://my-dns.com`.